# Why does std::map::insert docs refer to a key argument that does not exist

Tags: c++, stl

I am looking at the docs for [std::map::insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/).

The function signature with a "hint" is defined as follows....

```
with hint (2)   
iterator insert (const_iterator position, const value_type& val);
template <class P> iterator insert (const_iterator position, P&& val);
```

Then the subsequent description of the return value for that particular implementation of insert is as follows...

> The versions with a hint (2) return an iterator pointing to either the
>   newly inserted element or to the element that already had an
>   equivalent key in the map.

But this doesn't make any sense, as I never provided a key as an argument to this function, only a value.

So what exactly will it return?

Comment: [`value_type` is `std::pair<const Key, T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).  If you provide a value_type, you have provided a key .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key is a part of value you pass to the `value_type`.

You pass value something like below, in which "1" is key and "100" is value.

```
std::pair<int,int>(1,100)
```

or

```
 std::make_pair(1, 100)
```

example:

```
std::map<int, int> testmap;

testmap.insert(testmap.begin(),std::make_pair(1, 100));
testmap.insert(testmap.begin(),std::pair<int,int>(2, 100));
```